# Getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) while trying to copy matching filenames from csv to another directory

Tags: python, file, csv, file-handling, valueerror

Hi I am trying to copy the files mentioned in a csv from one directory to the other but getting this error. Code till now:

```
import os
import shutil
import csv
import sys

csv_file = "C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\bha.csv"
existing_path_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\5KFILES\\'
new_path_prefix =  'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\err\\'

with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for (i, row) in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0:
            print(i)
            pass    # Skip header row
        else:
            filename, filepath = row
            new_filename = os.path.join(new_path_prefix, filename)
            old_filename = os.path.join(filepath, filename)
            shutil.copy(old_filename, new_filename)
```

Printing out the row looks like this:

```
['05-18-18 Letter from BA - DMFLTR _20984_ IR.txt']
['05-18-18 Letter from CA NDA 20758s74 ACK Letter.txt']
['05-21-18 Letter from CBE 30-IR Gr.txt']
['05-24-18 Letter from FA 020872.txt']
['05-Mar-2018 - CBER Acknowledgement - 2198519.txt']
['05-Sept-2018 - CBER Approval - CCR 2229614 - Switch from AD.txt']
['05.10.2018 Cea Approval, var 15G.txt']
```

Comment: The problem is that the variable "row" doesn't contain what you think it contains. Try printing it out? (and tell us what it is)

Comment: It contains a separate list of each filename

Comment: @BilzzM can you share with us how it looks?

Comment: Please check the updated code

Comment: row is a list, you are using it the wrong way. It has to be accessed by using some index.

Comment: The issue was with the csv. Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1):

According to your CSV's your row is basically `['somestring']` and to unpack to a tuple you need a list/tuple with at least two elements.

Basically each row should look like: `filename, filepath = ['some filename', 'some filepath']`

Using regex you could do:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("([a-zA-Z 0-9 \-_.,]+) (\w+\.\w+)")
match = re.search(pattern, '05-18-18 Letter from BA - DMFLTR _20984_ IR.txt')

print(match.group(1))
print(match.group(2))
```

which yields

```
05-18-18 Letter from BA - DMFLTR _20984_
IR.txt
```

so basically all you need to do is to pass row to the `re.search(pattern, row)` and then take the filename and filepath as:

```
filename = match.group(1)
filepath = match.group(2)
```

Comment: @BlizzM well your CSV isn't formatted correctly in the first place. Because you want to store `05-18-18 Letter from BA - DMFLTR _20984_ IR.txt` into two variables. Do you have a better CSV?

Comment: What could be done alternatively is use regex to capture the filename and filepath, but it really depends on all the rows if for all of them the filename looks like `something.txt`

Comment: The issue was with the csv. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: @BilzzM check out my answer how you could do it alternatively with `re`. Please mark the answer if it helped you btw.